# Wordpress show different element if current date is two between dates

Tags: php, wordpress, date

There are 4 seasons in my Wordpress template. Each season has a start and end date.

This is my current date:

```
$currentDate = date('d-m') . '-' . date('Y');
$currentDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($currentDate)); //output 16-05-19
```

Example of season 1 start and end date:

```
$season_1_start = get_sub_field('start_date','option');
$season_1_start = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($season_1_start));

$season_1_end = get_sub_field('end_date','option');
$season_1_end = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($season_1_end));
```

The output of the season dates is also 'd-m-Y'.

How can I check if `$currentdate` is between `$season_1_start` and `$season_1_end`

So:

```
if (($currentDate >= $season_1_start) && ($currentDate <= $season_1_end)){
    echo "season 1";
}
if (($currentDate >= $season_2_start) && ($currentDate <= $season_2_end)){
    echo "season 2";
 }

if (($currentDate >= $season_3_start) && ($currentDate <= $season_3_end)){
    echo "season 3";
 }

if (($currentDate >= $season_4_start) && ($currentDate <= $season_4_end)){
     echo "season 4";
}
```

But my output is `season 1season 2season 3season 4`
So it seems that every if statement is true.

I've already checked if the season dates are correct and I don't see anything wrong with them.

The result should be, today, `season 2`

Comment: I'm not used to WordPress, but does `get_sub_field('start_date','option');` return up to 4 different values? How do you get the different start and end-dates of the season?

Comment: That function simply gives the start date in this format 'd/m' But actually it doesnt matter if this is made in Wordpress. $season_1_start value output will be forexample 01/01 and $season_1_end will be 31/03

Comment: That is not an easily “comparable” date format - so unless you want to create real DateTime objects from that to be able to do the comparison, you should first of all change that format. The other way around, `m/d`, it becomes comparable using simple string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well versed with WordPress, but seems like something you can easily solve in plain PHP.

You can use the DateTime class to compare against the current date today. Since your format isn't standard, we can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. This creates a DateTime object based on the format you provide - which in your case is `d/m`. Since no year is specified, it uses the current year.

You might need to adjust the conditions to `>=` or `<=`, depending on what dates your ranges are defined within.

```php
$today = new DateTime;
$season_1_start = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m", get_sub_field('start_date','option'));
$season_1_end = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m", get_sub_field('end_date','option'));

if ($today > $season_1_start && $today < $season_1_end) {
    // Season 1
}
```

Then do  the same for your other seasons.

Comment: It seems that DateTime is not recognized.

Comment: Do I have to define DateTime somewhere in orde to make that work? 
Sorry, don't know much about php...

Comment: DateTime is a native class in all PHP versions above  5.2.0. Are you running a version lower than that? Do a `echo phpversion();`

Comment: My PHP version is 7.1.8 But I'm getting a bit closer to the solution :-) I've updated my question above.

Comment: You might have to address the namespace, ie `\DateTime`